# Sympfony Request (AndWhere, OrWhere) with conditions

Tags: php, sql, symfony, dql

I have 2 DQL queries

I want the user (with a select form) to be able to select:

1. 1 filter at a time. Either party or city

or

2. several filters at the same time: party + city ... then others afterwards.

In summary :
In my database there are Party and City. With a form of select. The user must be able to choose the filters he wants. If he chose a particular Party without specifying the city, this will display all the Party in all the City. He can also choose a city, in which case he will have all the party of the chosen city. or 3rd case, he chose an Party + a City.

When one works the other is not.
I think I have a problem with my conditions and operators.
I read that using the orWhere () was bad practice.

Thanking you in advance.

```
 public function searchByParty($party, $city)
{

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');
    $query = $query
        ->select( 'party', 'city', 's')
        ->join ('s.party', 'party ')
        ->join ('s.city', 'city');

   
    if (!empty($party) === !empty($city))  {
        $query = $query
            ->andWhere('party .id = :sport')
            ->andWhere('city.id = :city')
            ->setParameter('party ', $party )
            ->setParameter('city', $city);
    }

    if (!empty($party) && !empty($city)) {
        $query = $query
            ->orWhere('party.id = :party')
            ->orWhere('city.id = :city')
            ->setParameter('party', $party )
            ->setParameter('city', $city);
    }

    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: `!empty($party) === !empty($city)`  looks weird it will run if both has value and both are empty.What exactly is your requirement and the issue you are facing can you add some more details

Answer (score 0):

You have a logical issue. Your first `if` checks whether the existence of `$party` and `$city` is equivalent, which is true if and only if both exists or both does not exist. It does not make sense to check for their value if they both do not exist. The second `if` checks whether neither is defined. In that case it does not make sense to check the value against them. Fix:

```
public function searchByParty($party, $city) {

$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');
$query = $query
    ->select( 'party', 'city', 's')
    ->join ('s.party', 'party ')
    ->join ('s.city', 'city');


if (!empty($party)) {
    $query = $query
        ->andWhere('party .id = :sport')
        ->setParameter('party ', $party )
}

if (!empty($city)) {
    $query = $query
        ->andWhere('city.id = :city')
        ->setParameter('city', $city);
}

return $query->getQuery()->getResult();

}
```

EDIT: if you want to check whether any of them matches, then use orWhere:

```
public function searchByParty($party, $city) {

$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');
$query = $query
    ->select( 'party', 'city', 's')
    ->join ('s.party', 'party ')
    ->join ('s.city', 'city');


if (!empty($party)) {
    $query = $query
        ->orWhere('party .id = :sport')
        ->setParameter('party ', $party )
}

if (!empty($city)) {
    $query = $query
        ->orWhere('city.id = :city')
        ->setParameter('city', $city);
}

return $query->getQuery()->getResult();

}
```

Comment: @Dev you do realize that "several filters at the same time: party + city ... then others afterwards." can be interpreted in infinitely many ways, right? You did not provide sample data, nor criteria. Your question remains very vague and lacks preciseness.

Comment: Let's suppose that the value passed for party is "foo" and the value passed for city is "New York". What records should appear in the result? If a record's party is "foo", but it's city is "Amsterdam", should that record appear in the results because its party matches "foo", or should it not appear among the results, because its city does not match "Amsterdam"?

Comment: Your issue is primarily logical, it seems you are not yet experienced/knowledgable about the application of logical operands to correctly evaluate your criteria. But before you reach any solution you should be able to formulate the problem **properly** first to yourself and then, if stuck, then in the question.

Comment: You should think this through and tell us what should happen if 1. party is not matched, city is not matched (probably the record should not appear in the result), 2. party is not matched, city is matched (???), 3. party is matched but city is not matched (???), 4. both matches (probably the record should appear in the results). "does not work" is not only too vague, but shows the lack of effort to formulate the problem. First of all, you will need to make some effort in describing what the problem is. If you do not do so, you will have difficulties solving these logical problems.

Comment: In my database there are Party and City.
With a form of select.
The user must be able to choose the filters he wants.
If he chose a particular Party without specifying the city, this will display all the Party in all the City.
He can also choose a city, in which case he will have all the party of the chosen city.
or 3rd case, he chose an Party + a City.

Comment: @Dev **and what should happen if both a party and a city is chosen?** My last attempt to find out what your question is about.

Comment: this is option 3. "or 3rd case, he chose an Party + a City."
Either it displays a result or none

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
     public function searchBySession($party, $city)
{

    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');
        $query = $query
            ->select( 's');

        if($party){
            $query = $query
                ->join ('s.party', 'party')
                ->addSelect('party')
                ->andWhere('party.id = :party')
                ->setParameter('party', $party)
            ;
        }

        if($city){
            $query = $query
                ->join ('s.city', 'city')
                ->addSelect('city')
                ->andWhere('city.id = :city')
                ->setParameter('city', $city)
            ;
        }

    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Thanks you